# Looking for help migrating a wordpress site:

Tags: wordpress, migration

**BACK STORY:**

So i was having issues with GO DADDY as usual and my Wordpress blog got deleted.  I had used UPDraft Backup Plug In to back up my site to Google Drive.

After GO DADDY shut down my hosting AND domain (i have to wait 3 months til i can reclaim the domain) i lost everything.

**CURRENTLY:**

I got new hosting and got another domain name.  I wanted to migrate my old wordpress site to the new host and domain.

I installed Wordpress and then installed UpDraft Backup Plugin.  When i installed my site backup the old domain name is causing conflict so now my wordpress admin login is switching to the old domain even though i'm using the new domain.

As of now i can't do anything on Wordpress.  Not even log in.  I know there was a plugin i was to use along with UpDraft Backup.  Don't know if i was suppose to use it before or after the migration.

So I'm looking for solutions.  Is there a way to edit some files in my old wordpess site to get this to work.

Is my only hope to delete the new installation of Wordpress on my hosting server and start over.

I hope i explained this clearly.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

if you have a little bit wordperss knowledge then go to your wp-config.php file placeed in the root of your wodpress setup. edit the file and paste the below code in the file.

replaec the word "yournewsiteurl" to your site url

```
define('WP_HOME','http://yournewsiteurl.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://yournewsiteurl.com');
```

hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

use this line of code to update your new site urls. Place these two lines in your funcions.php file

```
update_option('home','http://new-location-example.com');
update_option('siteurl','http://new-location-example.com');
```

Replace http://new-location-example.com with your current new url.

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL should explain this in detail with änder above.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the following code on your MySQL This will change all URL's on your existing wordpress websites.

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = REPLACE(option_value, 'oldsite.com', 'newsite.com');
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = REPLACE(meta_value, 'oldsite.com', 'newsite.com');
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, 'oldsite.com', 'newsite.com');
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_excerpt = REPLACE(post_excerpt, 'oldsite.com', 'newsite.com');
UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = REPLACE(guid, 'oldsite.com', 'newsite.com');
```

I hope this will provide a solution to your question